# Sub drawable Folders in minSDK v3 Project?

Tags: android, resources, drawable, android-resolution

When you create a project with min SDK version = 3 , you will not see the three auto-generated folders `drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, and drawable-hdpi`.

Is it possible to add them ? I know that I can add the folders I need in the project but I want to know if the Android System will consider the resources as alternative or will take the default folder (`drawable`) and scale what's inside it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I did some research, and as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7161987/543711), you can not have such folders when you targeting 1.5.

Thanks